# Incompatible pointer type initializing TaggedUIActionAheet with an expression of type UIActionSheet

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiactionsheet

When I run this:

```
TaggedUIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
        initWithTitle:nil
        delegate:self 
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
        destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
        otherButtonTitles:@"Save to photos",@"Email",nil];
```

I get the following error :

`Incompatible pointer type initializing TaggedUIActionAheet with an expression of type UIActionSheet`

Answer (score 1):

Spot the error in your first line:

```
TaggedUIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
```

Should be:

```
TaggedUIActionSheet *sheet = [[TaggedUIActionSheet alloc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 UIActionSheet *Actionsheet =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:title delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:Canclebutton destructiveButtonTitle:destructivebutton otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[Actionsheet showInView:self.view];

-(void)Click_Button:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self ShowActionsheet:@"Do u Want to Delete This Record!!!" Delegate:self canclebutton:@"Cancle" Destructivebutton:@"Yes"];
}
```